# jQuery - Animating opacity in IE8

Tags: jquery, animation, internet-explorer-8, opacity

On the site I'm currently working on I have an `<ul>` containing a load of `<li>`'s, which each contain `<div>`, `<span>`, `<img>` etc.

When I hover over one of the `<li>`'s, I'm using jQuery to animate the opacity of all the *other* `<li>`'s to 0.3 to draw attention to the focused `<li>`.

My problem is IE8 (and **only** IE8) is animating the `<li>`'s opacity, but none of the child elements within that `<li>`.

Anybody come across this issue before, or know of a fix?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Please see the following jsFiddle for an example - http://jsfiddle.net/BJ8gK/22/

Comment: post your code in a jsfiddle or something

Comment: I can't replicate the issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/BJ8gK/.  Can you be more specific about your HTML and your jQuery code that does the animation.

Comment: You **have to** post some code!  We're not mind-readers.

Comment: FYI, IE uses `filter` to control opacity and `filter` only applies to children objects in some circumstances, but those circumstances are specific to your HTML and your CSS.

Comment: Apologies, please see the following jsFiddle for an example. I can confirm the issue is replicated in my IE8 - http://jsfiddle.net/BJ8gK/22/

Answer (score 16):

I had a similar problem - in IE8 order to ensure child elements' opacity is also affected when changing the opacity of their parent element you have to apply the css rule

```
filter:inherit
```

to the child elements.  Simple fix, but perhaps obscure

Comment: This solved my problems. I am showing/hiding <section>'s with a jquery inview plugin. and there child elements were always visible.

Answer (score 0):

IE8's opacity support is well known to be extremely flaky and buggy.

jQuery does a good job of abstracting the details away from you as a developer, but they can't avoid the simple fact that the feature does not work well in this browser.

My recommendation would be to change tack completely, and instead of fading out the element you can see, instead have a hidden element which is a plain white box the same size, and fade that in instead.

The effect will be much the same, but should work better in IE because you'll only be affecting the opacity of a single element.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to animate opacity on rows in a [Datatable](http://datatables.net/) and found that JQuery 1.10 does try and solve the IE8 opacity internally. It does not however fix the inherited elements issue. This fragment of code, which adds and shows a new row on a paginated table, may help others:

```js
// add the row to the table
newRow = dTable.row.add(rowData);
dTable.draw();
newIdx = newRow.index();
pos = dTable.rows()[0].indexOf(newIdx);
// draw item on correct page, from page.jumpToData()
if (pos >= 0) {
  var page = Math.floor(pos / dTable.page.info().length);
  dTable.page(page).draw(false);
  var jqRow = newRow.nodes().to$();
  var cells = jqRow.children('th,td');
  if (editable > 0) {
     // focus on first editable cell in new row...
     cells.eq(editable).click();
  }
  // child elements need to inherit - see answer by Buzz
  cells.css( 'filter', 'inherit');
  jqRow.addClass('highlight').css('opacity', 0.2);
  jqRow.animate({opacity: 1.0});
  jqRow.animate({opacity: 0.2});
  jqRow.animate({opacity: 1.0}, 2000, 'swing', function () {
  $(this).removeClass('highlight');
});
```